# Bigquery LTRIM function with multiple CONDITIONS

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the below statement to remove one condition i.e 'TPR_' from a column.

```
(SELECT LTRIM(Field1,'TPR_')) as Parent8
```

I want to add a second condition 'TPR ' to the above query. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you add some sample outputs you are looking for ,along with the inputs? By second condition do you mean applying some filter on top of the trimmed value?

Answer (score 2):

Consider below

```
select regexp_replace(Field1, r'^TPR_?', '') as Parent8
```

Comment: Thanks.This looks promising. I have few values in Field1 like "TPR501 abc" and "TPR502 xyz"
. How can  I remove TPR501 and TPR502?

Comment: i.e remove anything attached to TPR

Answer (score 0):

LTRIM will remove all the provided symbols not just 'TPR_' substring:
[image]

Maybe you need a `STARTS_WITH` and `SUBSTR`:

```
(select if(starts_with(Field1, 'TPR_'), SUBSTR(Field1, 5), if(starts_with(Field1, 'TPR'), SUBSTR(Field1, 4), Field1))) as Parent8
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
select regexp_replace('ABC Salaries', r'^ABC*\w+', '') as Field1

Result:
"ABC Salaries" replaced with Salaries
"ABC501 Salaries" replaced with Salaries
```